# Is selfishness the ultimate form of liberation?

Tags: ethics

Is selfishness free of guilt a form of liberation? Personally, I don't see where the selfish are going wrong, if the entire reward system is wired to fire on materialistic stimuli, how can, from a plainly scientific perspective, selfishness be wrong?

Comment: If it is about liberation why care about a reward system? Isn't freedom its own reward? If one simply wishes to be selfish one is free to declare *that* morally good, see [Ethical egoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_egoism).

Comment: Up to the point that you're shot for being an asshole.

Comment: From a purely scientific perspective, there's no right or wrong (although the psychology of ethics could well be scientific).  Science in various forms can be very useful when we have a goal we wish to achieve, but it can't set that goal.  What do you mean by "from a plainly scientific perspective"?

Comment: Lmfao why was my comment removed, it contained exactly the same amount of content that Conifold's has

Answer (score 1):

There is a solid scientific case to be made, that anyone must first look after themselves, to best be of use to others. But you are asking, why be of use to others? What makes us distinctly human is reprogrammable instincts and [eusociality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusociality). This is further underpinned by the Private Language argument, that our capacity to think complex thoughts has relied fundamentally on community development of language, and our enculturation through childhood by communities. So, you can choose to be a freerider, taking the benefits of living in comnunity. But it will be in society and evolutions interest to limit your influence and wipe you from the record if so.

You can see how arguing the other way fails though, that we should live primarily selflessly for others or whatever. It plays out in the fall of the concept of group selection, and rise of multi-level selection. Groups cannot supercede the gene as primary level of selection, or the freerider problem is magnified unsustainably. But, selection can take place on multiple levels, and this can be used to explain the incremental emergence of eusociality and other behaviours.

You might say utopian movements including 'pure' communism attempt to make the group primary, over the well being of individuals. And that systems which maintain habeus corpus, free speech, and other guarantees of individual autonomy have been far more stable, but only if they can also move beyond tribalism, factionalism, and it might be suggested - identity politics.

Durkheim identified [religion as sources of 'cameraderie and solidarity'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Durkheim#Religion). His analysis of religious instincts as forming societies in moral community bound together by relationship to sacred things can be generalised beyond it's relevance to religion. For instance, to values like habeus corpus, sovereignty of parliament, free speech, human rights etc. We can also see the emergence of early civilisation and values supporting multilevel selection, both in the archeological record such as [Gobekli Tepe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6bekli_Tepe), and in early religious narratives such asnof the children of Cain which seems to be about the clash of individualistic and honour-based herding communities and the nore communal attitude needed by agriculturalists to sow and harvest together. Sharing values about what is sacred binds people together across tribal and resource conflicts. Choosing to ignore or scorn what a society holds sacred may put you outside it, or even make the enemy of the whole group. Although you may be able to navigate your selfish interests in a way which doesn't conflict.

[Matt Taibi](https://youtu.be/uecEK6LYycQ)
as a journalist as a journalist of financial crashes has interesting things to say on the inevitability that businesses will exploit avenues to profit available to them, and the crucialness of limitations on business and individual autonomy to prevent ethical races to the bottom, which he describes on a focus on accountability, but not indelible records.

TLDR: Personal development and intelligence are supported by being in community with others, if you choose to be a freerider you will be marginalised from these benefits. Many people who forget this even on the path to great fortunes, do not end up happy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that individual psychology is not as what it seems to be because it will always consider how the individual will relate to the society despite his own effect on himself, otherwise psychopathy and megalomania won't be considered a psychological disorders. These disorders surely have no negative effects on the individual in terms of biology as they make him guilt-free, when no other "normal" man is guilt-free, however they are still considered disorders because of their impact on the society. If man entire behavior is only motivated by desire without being governed by guilt, then this man is a psychopath. He's good for himself as he is spared the existential guilt that we all suffer from, but he's not good for others. We already know the type of the world that can accept multiple psychopaths, which is the asylum.